# Javascript redirect vs PHP redirect, which would search engines see as regular content

Tags: php, javascript, redirect, search-engine

I'm guessing that using PHP's header("location: here.html") would be much better javascript's window.location("here.html") as far as search engine visibility goes. I would assume that the server redirect would show google the correct content and the javascript redirect would be read as a page with the javascript redirect code in it.

Reason being is I have a client that wants me to take their current website and import it into a CMS system (I'm using e107) and I don't want their old pages to lose their current page rank. I was thinking of putting redirects on the old pages to the new pages in the CMS system.

Comment: `header("location: here.html")` is not technically valid and I know that Google complains when it appears in sitemaps. You should use a full, not a relative, URL.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The only way to forward on search engine rank is with an HTTP 301 (permanent) redirect.

Using PHP's [`header('Location')`](http://php.net/header) will give a 302 unless you specify the code like this:

```
header('Location: http://....', true, 301);
```

It might be easier to use .htaccess, like this:

```
RewriteRule ^old.php /new.php [R=301]
```

Comment: I've always liked the apache RewriteRule best - it provides a clean place to put all your old-to-new page forwarding.

Answer (score 6):

Yes, you want to do server side redirection (PHP) if you can.

```
<?
Header( "HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently" );
Header( "Location: http://www.new-url.com" );
?>
```

[via](http://www.webconfs.com/how-to-redirect-a-webpage.php)

You can also do this using

```
header("location: http://www.new-url.com")
```

but it won't be as good SEO wise